Is $(S^n \times S^1)/ \{\pm 1\}$ the mapping torus of antipodal map of $S^n$?
I have a doubt. Consider the product space of a $n$ sphere and a circle $S^1$. Now if we consider $(S^n \times S^1)/ \{\pm 1\}$ where scalar multiplication by $-1$ acts by antipodal map on both the $S^n$ and and $S^1$ factor.
But in the paper (page 8) it is written that $(S^n \times S^1)/ \{\pm 1\}$ is the mapping torus of antipodal map of $S^n$.
Can anyone please help me to understand this?
Please help me.

I know what the antipodal action of $\mathbb Z_2$ is on $S^1$ in particular and on $S^n$ in general. But what do you mean by the antipodal action on $S^n \times S^1$?

You would get $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n \times S^1$ from $\mathbb{Z} / 2$ acting on each factor separately, i.e. as the space $(S^n \times S^1) / (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \times \mathbb{Z} / 2)$, but here $\mathbb{Z} / 2$ acts on the diagonal.

You should not add a new question. You should instead hit the edit button and fix this question.

@LeeMosher Edited

Perhaps you should start by editing your post to include the definition of the mapping torus of $f(x)=-x$. Do you seem anything suggestive?
